# Escaping whitespace on a macOS shell script

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, rsync

I am running an issue when running the following script on macOS using macOS built-in `rsync` version (rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29).

The script backups some files and folders to a specific folder in my dropbox, and is ran at a specific time by a plist macOS launch daemon.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Halt the script on any errors.
set -e

target_path="/Users/alex/Dropbox/backup"

# Create the target path if it doesn't exist.
mkdir -p "${target_path}"

# A list of absolute paths to backup.
things3="${HOME}/Library/Containers/com.culturedcode.ThingsMac/Data/Library/Application Support/Cultured Code/Things/Things.sqlite3"

include_paths=(
  "${HOME}/.ssh"
  "$things3"
  # [...]
)

# A list of folder names and files to exclude.
exclude_paths=(
  # [...]
)

# rsync allows you to exclude certain paths.
for item in "${exclude_paths[@]}"
do
  exclude_flags="${exclude_flags} --exclude='"${item}"'"
done

# rsync allows you to pass in a list of paths to copy.
for item in "${include_paths[@]}"
do
  include_args="${include_args} --include='"${item}"'"
done


# Finally, we just run rsync
rsync -avR --dry-run ${exclude_flags} ${include_args} ${target_path}
```

I am facing the following error, any idea why this problem occurs?

```
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/alex/Dropbox/bin/" failed: No such file or directory (2) rsync: 
link_stat "/Users/alex/bin/ --include='/Users/alex/.ssh' --include='/Users/alex/Library/Containers/com.culturedcode.ThingsMac/Data/Library/Application Support/Cultured Code/Things/Things.sqlite3'" failed: No such file or directory (2) done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays for the `*_flags` values as well. The whitespace isn't escaped by the quotes you are adding to the strings; those quotes are literal parts of the data, not shell syntax, after the unquoted parameter expansions.

```
for item in "${exclude_paths[@]}"; do
  exclude_flags+=(--exclude "$item")
done

for item in "${include_paths[@]}"; do
  include_flags+=(--include "$item")
done

rsync -avR --dry-run "${exclude_flags[@]}" "${include_args[@]}" "${target_path}"
```